# TikZ: using the draw let in syntax to create an arc but the arc and its difference angle doesnt add up to 360

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax

Consider this code snippet:

```
\draw[-latex] let
        \p0 = (P6),
        \p1 = (P5),
        \p2 = (P4),
        \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
        \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
        \n3 = {.75cm},
        \n4 = {(\n2 + \n1) / 2}
      in (P6) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
```

This comes from the code below (at the bottom):

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, backgrounds, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{circle with radius/.style = {shape = circle, inner sep = 0pt,
      outer sep = 0pt, minimum size = {2 * (#1)}}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round,
    every label/.append style = {font = \scriptsize},
    dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
      draw = black, label = {#1}},
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
    ]
    \begin{scope}
      %\clip ($(B) + (1.5, -2)$) rectangle ($(B) + (-3, 2)$);                       

      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

      \pgfmathsetmacro{\as}{3}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\bs}{2.25}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\as^2 - \bs^2)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\al}{3.75}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\bl}{2.9}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cl}{sqrt(\al^2 - \bl^2)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xs}{abs(\c - \cl)}

      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

      \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(F\)}] (F) at (\c, 0) {};

      \path[name path global = line1] (\c, 0) -- ++(60:{\as} and \bs);
      \path[name path global = line2] (\c, 0) -- ++(150:6cm);
    
    \draw[name path global = ell1, blue] (O) ellipse
        (\as cm and \bs cm);

        \draw[name path global = ell2, red] (-\xs, 0)
        ellipse (\al cm and \bl cm);

      \path[name intersections = {of = line1 and ell1, by = P1}];
      \node[fill = black, big dot = {right: \(A\)}] (A) at (P1) {};

      \path[name intersections = {of = line2 and ell2, by = P2}];
      \node[fill = black, big dot = {above: \(B\)}] (B) at (P2) {};

      \begin{scope}[declare function = {doubleA = 5.8cm;},
        ]
        \clip ($(A.center) + (1, 0)$) rectangle ($(B.center) + (0, 1)$);
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
          \path let
            \p1 = ($(A) - (F)$),
            \p2 = ($(B) - (F)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1, \y1)},
            \n2 = {veclen(\x2, \y2)}
          in
          (A) node[name path global = aCircle, circle with radius = doubleA-\n1]
          {}
          (B) node[name path global = bCircle, circle with radius = doubleA-\n2]
          {}
          (F) node[name path global = fCircle,
          circle with radius = .5 * doubleA] {};

          \tikzset{name intersections = {of = aCircle and bCircle, name = F'} }
          \foreach \solA in {2} {
            \path ($(F)!.5!(F'-\solA)$) coordinate (C'-\solA)
            ($(C'-\solA)!doubleA/2!(F)$) coordinate (xDir-\solA)
            (F'-\solA) node[name path global/.expanded = f'Circle-\solA,
            circle with radius = .5 * doubleA] {};
          }                         %!?      
          \foreach \solA in {2} { %!?                                               
            \path[name intersections = {of = fCircle and f'Circle-\solA,
              by = {yDir-\solA}}]
            ($(xDir-\solA)-(C'-\solA)$) coordinate (xDir'-\solA)
            ($(yDir-\solA)-(C'-\solA)$) coordinate (yDir'-\solA)
            ;
          }
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \foreach \solA in {2}
        \draw[x = (xDir'-\solA), y = (yDir'-\solA), name path global = traj]
        (C'-\solA) circle [radius = 1];
      \end{scope}

      \path[name path = circ] (B) circle [radius = 1bp];

      \draw[name intersections = {of = circ and traj}, -latex] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!1.25cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P3);
      \draw[name intersections = {of = circ and ell2}, -latex, red] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!2cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P4);
      \draw[-latex, name path = line3] (P3) -- (P4);
      \draw[name path = line4] (B) -- ($(B)!2.1cm!-90:(F)$) coordinate (P5);

      \path[name path = circ2] (P3) circle [radius = 1bp];
      \path[name intersections = {of = circ2 and line3}, name path = line5]
      (P3) -- ($(intersection-1)!2cm!(P3)$);
      \path[name intersections = {of = line5 and line4, by = P6}];

      \path[name intersections = {of = circ and traj}] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!1.5cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P7);

      \path[name intersections = {of = circ and ell2}] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!2.5cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P8);
      
      \draw[-latex] let
        \p0 = (P6),
        \p1 = (P5),
        \p2 = (P4),
        \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
        \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
        \n3 = {.75cm},
        \n4 = {(\n2 + \n1) / 2}
      in (P6) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So in this draw command, I set 0th point as the focus, the 1st point as the starting angle line, and the 2nd point as the ending angle line.  However, the TikZ picture arcs the opposite direction (see below):

[image]

So I then took `\n2 = {2 * pi - atan2(..)}` which should be wedge not encircled with the arc but this generate this picture:

[image]

Those two arcs should theoretically add up to a full circle.

> What is going wrong?
>
> How can I get the command to arc to the correct distance?

If I compile both commands, we can see without a doubt they aren't adding up:

[image]

---

**Edit 2:**

Consider the image below:

[image]

As to why I used the code above as MWE, we can see that I have arcs in the same vicinity that had negative angles as well.  I defined those arcs just as I did the one that posed a problem.  Therefore, it appeared to be an issue with that area not negative angles.

For instance, gamma2 was defined focus, lower line, and upper line but it drew the arc without needing special treatment unlike the phi angle I asked here about.

Comment: Do you really have to include all the irrelevant parts to the question? It's just an arc problem and you have two pages of code. Why don't you try something simpler to isolate the problem.

Comment: @percusse I wasn't sure if it was related to that area since my other arcs in that same area worked just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trigonometric functions in PGF use degrees, so you'll have to use `360` instead of `2*pi`, and you'll have to deduct the full circle from the angle, not the other way round.

This becomes clear if you make a minimal example and look at the angles. The `delta angle` of the arc is the `end angle` minus the `start angle`. In your case, you have a delta angle that's larger than 180°, so you get the large arc. By subtracting a full circle from the end angle, the absolute value of the difference angle becomes smaller than 180°:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=right:O] (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below:A] (A) at (-1,-1.5);
\coordinate [label=left:B] (B) at (-2,1);
\draw (A) -- (O) -- (B);

\draw [-latex] 
    let
        \p0 = (O),
        \p1 = (A),
        \p2 = (B),
        \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
        \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
        \n3 = {1cm}
    in
        (\p0) + (\n1:\n3) arc [radius=\n3, start angle=\n1, end angle=\n2]
    node [anchor=west, align=right] at (1.5,0) {\verb|\n1|: \pgfmathparse{\n1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\\ \verb|\n2|: \pgfmathparse{\n2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\\
    delta: \pgfmathparse{\n2-\n1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=right:O] (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below:A] (A) at (-1,-1.5);
\coordinate [label=left:B] (B) at (-2,1);
\draw (A) -- (O) -- (B);

\draw [-latex] 
    let
        \p0 = (O),
        \p1 = (A),
        \p2 = (B),
        \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
        \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0) - 360},
        \n3 = {1cm}
    in
        (\p0) + (\n1:\n3) arc [radius=\n3, start angle=\n1, end angle=\n2]
    node [anchor=west, align=right] at (1.5,0) {\verb|\n1|: \pgfmathparse{\n1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\\ \verb|\n2|: \pgfmathparse{\n2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\\
    delta: \pgfmathparse{\n2-\n1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, backgrounds, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{circle with radius/.style = {shape = circle, inner sep = 0pt,
      outer sep = 0pt, minimum size = {2 * (#1)}}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round,
    every label/.append style = {font = \scriptsize},
    dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
      draw = black, label = {#1}},
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
    ]
    \begin{scope}
      %\clip ($(B) + (1.5, -2)$) rectangle ($(B) + (-3, 2)$);                       

      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

      \pgfmathsetmacro{\as}{3}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\bs}{2.25}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\as^2 - \bs^2)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\al}{3.75}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\bl}{2.9}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cl}{sqrt(\al^2 - \bl^2)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xs}{abs(\c - \cl)}

      \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

      \node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(F\)}] (F) at (\c, 0) {};

      \path[name path global = line1] (\c, 0) -- ++(60:{\as} and \bs);
      \path[name path global = line2] (\c, 0) -- ++(150:6cm);

    \draw[name path global = ell1, blue] (O) ellipse
        (\as cm and \bs cm);

        \draw[name path global = ell2, red] (-\xs, 0)
        ellipse (\al cm and \bl cm);

      \path[name intersections = {of = line1 and ell1, by = P1}];
      \node[fill = black, big dot = {right: \(A\)}] (A) at (P1) {};

      \path[name intersections = {of = line2 and ell2, by = P2}];
      \node[fill = black, big dot = {above: \(B\)}] (B) at (P2) {};

      \begin{scope}[declare function = {doubleA = 5.8cm;},
        ]
        \clip ($(A.center) + (1, 0)$) rectangle ($(B.center) + (0, 1)$);
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
          \path let
            \p1 = ($(A) - (F)$),
            \p2 = ($(B) - (F)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1, \y1)},
            \n2 = {veclen(\x2, \y2)}
          in
          (A) node[name path global = aCircle, circle with radius = doubleA-\n1]
          {}
          (B) node[name path global = bCircle, circle with radius = doubleA-\n2]
          {}
          (F) node[name path global = fCircle,
          circle with radius = .5 * doubleA] {};

          \tikzset{name intersections = {of = aCircle and bCircle, name = F'} }
          \foreach \solA in {2} {
            \path ($(F)!.5!(F'-\solA)$) coordinate (C'-\solA)
            ($(C'-\solA)!doubleA/2!(F)$) coordinate (xDir-\solA)
            (F'-\solA) node[name path global/.expanded = f'Circle-\solA,
            circle with radius = .5 * doubleA] {};
          }                         %!?      
          \foreach \solA in {2} { %!?                                               
            \path[name intersections = {of = fCircle and f'Circle-\solA,
              by = {yDir-\solA}}]
            ($(xDir-\solA)-(C'-\solA)$) coordinate (xDir'-\solA)
            ($(yDir-\solA)-(C'-\solA)$) coordinate (yDir'-\solA)
            ;
          }
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \foreach \solA in {2}
        \draw[x = (xDir'-\solA), y = (yDir'-\solA), name path global = traj]
        (C'-\solA) circle [radius = 1];
      \end{scope}

      \path[name path = circ] (B) circle [radius = 1bp];

      \draw[name intersections = {of = circ and traj}, -latex] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!1.25cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P3);
      \draw[name intersections = {of = circ and ell2}, -latex, red] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!2cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P4);
      \draw[-latex, name path = line3] (P3) -- (P4);
      \draw[name path = line4] (B) -- ($(B)!2.1cm!-90:(F)$) coordinate (P5);

      \path[name path = circ2] (P3) circle [radius = 1bp];
      \path[name intersections = {of = circ2 and line3}, name path = line5]
      (P3) -- ($(intersection-1)!2cm!(P3)$);
      \path[name intersections = {of = line5 and line4, by = P6}];

      \path[name intersections = {of = circ and traj}] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!1.5cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P7);

      \path[name intersections = {of = circ and ell2}] (B) --
      ($(intersection-1)!2.5cm!(intersection-2)$) coordinate (P8);

      \draw[-latex] let
        \p0 = (P6),
        \p1 = (P5),
        \p2 = (P4),
        \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
        \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)-360},
        \n3 = {.75cm}
      in (P6) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];

          \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know why I have to make to subtract 360 at all?  Why didn't it just operate in this direction in the first place?

Comment: @dustin: I've edited my answer. Again, making a minimal example before posting a question helps both the asker and other readers.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was related to that area since my other arcs in that same area worked just fine. So to me, it appeared such that I needed that area intact for the question.

Comment: @dustin: But in the process of building a minimal example, you would have found out what made the arc go the wrong way.

Comment: If you see the edit to my post, you will see that I had other negative angle arcs that were defined in the same manner but didn't cause this problem.  That is what made me think about it in the way I did, because with those negative angle arcs, I didn't need to subtract anything it just worked.

Comment: @dustin: It's not an issue with negative angles (they can be negative without problems, see my example), it's an issue with the absolute value of the difference between the angles: If it's larger than 180°, you get a large arc, if it's smaller than 180°, you get a small arc. In the picture in your edit, all the angles involved are negative (between -180° and 0°), therefore the absolute values of the differences are smaller than 180° as well. In the problematic case, one angle was positive (between 0° and 180°) and one was negative, leading to the large arc.

Comment: I didn't know that before; hence, I used a bigger example because I was under a different impression. Otherwise, I would have used a smaller example.  I post based on what I believe will replicate the issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9584/discussion-between-jake-and-dustin)